# Opencpu long running R analysis

Tags: r, opencpu

I have an R code which I am trying to call over HTTP using opencpu, but for the long running code, it is getting timeout. I came across https://github.com/joelkuiper/aplomb

Unfortunately, the documentation is not detailed and I am unable to figure out how to make it work once it is deployed and the container is running.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the file `/etc/opencpu/server.conf`

You should see parameters `timelimit.get` and `timelimit.post` (values are in seconds). Increase them to something that seems reasonable for your code, and save it.

Then restart the service:

```
sudo service opencpu restart
```

Then try again - hope it works!

Comment: Thank you, could you please let me know what can be the maximum value for timelimit as R code may sometime take about 15-20 mins to complete and also waiting the user for more than min or 2 would not be the right approach.

Comment: I don't know if there's a maximum but I have set it for 30 minutes in some cases and it seems to work. If you don't want the user to wait more than 2 minutes, you either need to break up your code into smaller pieces, or tell them that the processing will take a while and you will email or message them somehow when it completes.